# $L^2$ regularity theory for elliptic equations: Is there another method other that the difference quotient method? Reference request

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, linear-pde

So i'm interested in the following classical theorem or similar variants.

Consider the following elliptic PDE
$$
-D_\alpha(a^{ij}D_\beta u) = f.
$$
If we assume that the coefficients $a^{ij}$ are continuous, and we assume $f \in L^2$ and consider a weak solution $u \in H^1$ of that problem, then we have $u \in H^2_\textit{loc}$.

See for example the book on PDE by Evans, chapter 6 theorem 1 or the book *Introduction to the regularity theory for elliptic systems, harmonic maps and minimal graphs* by Giaquinta and Martinazzi. theorem 4.9 for the case of elliptic systems

So the general idea of the proof is using the difference quotient method, i.e. we define
$$
T_{h,s} u = \frac{u(x+he_s)-u(x)}{h}
$$ where $e_s$ is the standard basis vector in the direction $s$ and $h>0$ is small enough so that the quantity makes sense. This is a sort of discrete derivative, the idea is then to prove that the difference quotient of $Du$ for $u \in H^1$ is bounded for all sufficiently small $h$ in the $L^2$ norm and that will imply the result, for the detalis see the proofs in the mentioned books.

So I was wondering whether there is another method for proving that theorem that doesn't rely on difference quotients, I've searched on the internet but I haven't had any luck, so I'd be grateful if anyone could point out a reference or suggest where to look.

Comment: Do you mean purely at a technical level, or a genuinely different proof? The advantage of this proof is that it works directly for weak solutions. You can prove it by approximating the coefficients by smooth ones if you already have Schauder theory, then taking actual derivatives, and then passing to the limit, but this is sort of pointless. You can also look at proofs of perturbative Calderon-Zygmund theorems (even in Gilbarg Trudinger, like 9.11 or so), which imply this result after rewriting in nondivergence form and are substantively different (but harder, relying on additional ideas).

Comment: The proofs you are mentionning require more than just continuous : they use Lipschitz continuity. For example, in G-M,  $T_{h,s}A$ appears and then it is written $A$ is Lipschitz. In Evans, even more is assumed.

Answer (score 2):

You need more than continuous. Take $d=1$ and $f=0$. Then
$$
D(a D u)=0 \Rightarrow Du = \frac{C}{a},
$$
therefore $a\in C^0 \Leftrightarrow Du \in C^0$ (and that's it). To convince yourself that  $u\not\in H^2$ (if needs be) remember that then $u\in H^2\Rightarrow Du \in H^1$ and $H^1\hookrightarrow C^{0,\frac12}$, but $  \frac{C}{a} \not\in C^{0,\frac12}$.

For a non difference quotient proof, in the Lipschitz case, consider the ball $B_{1}=B\left(0,1\right)$.

Suppose that we know that if $f\in L^{2}\left(\Omega\right),$then
$u\in H_{0}^{1}\left(\Omega\right)$ the solution of
$$
-\Delta u=f\text{ in }B_{1},
$$
satisfies $u\in H^{2}\left(\Omega\right).$ Write.
\begin{align*}
S_{0}:L^{2}\left(\Omega\right) & \to H^{2}\left(\Omega\right)\cap H_{0}^{1}\left(\Omega\right)\\
f & \to u:-\Delta u=f\text{ in }B_{1}.
\end{align*}

Consider now $A=I_{d}+B,$ with $\left\Vert B\right\Vert _{W^{1,\infty}}\leq\eta\frac{1}{\left\Vert S_{0}\right\Vert _{L^{2}\to H^{2}\left(\Omega\right)\cap H_{0}^{1}\left(\Omega\right)}}.$
Set
\begin{align*}
T:H^{2}\left(\Omega\right)\cap H_{0}^{1}\left(\Omega\right) & \to H^{2}\left(\Omega\right)\cap H_{0}^{1}\left(\Omega\right)\\
u & \to S_{0}\left(\text{div}\left(B\nabla u\right)\right).
\end{align*}
Note that
$$
\text{div}\left(B\nabla u\right)=B_{ij}\partial_{ij}u+\left(\partial_{i}B_{ij}\right)\partial_{j}u\in L^{\infty}\times L^{2}+L^{\infty}\times H^{1}\subset L^{2},
$$
so indeed $T$ maps $H^{2}\left(\Omega\right)\cap H_{0}^{1}\left(\Omega\right)$
into itself. We have
$$
\left\Vert Tu\right\Vert _{H^{2}\cap H_{0}^{1}}\leq\left\Vert S_{0}\right\Vert _{L^{2}\to H^{2}\left(\Omega\right)\cap H_{0}^{1}\left(\Omega\right)}\left(\left\Vert B\right\Vert _{L^{\infty}}+\left\Vert \partial_{i}B_{ij}\right\Vert _{L^{\infty}}\right)\left\Vert u\right\Vert _{L^{2}},
$$
thus
$$
\left\Vert T\right\Vert _{H^{2}\cap H_{0}^{1}}\leq\eta.
$$

If $\eta<1$, then
\begin{align*}
S_{A}:L^{2}\left(\Omega\right) & \to H^{2}\left(\Omega\right)\cap H_{0}^{1}\left(\Omega\right)\\
f & \to u:-\text{div}\left(A\nabla u\right)=f\text{ in }B_{1}
\end{align*}
is well defined and
$$
S_{A}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}T^{k}S_{0}.
$$
The proof is simply to write

\begin{align*}
-\text{div}\left(\left(I_{d}-B\right)\nabla u\right) & =f\\
\Leftrightarrow S_{0}\left(-\text{div}\left(\left(I_{d}-B\right)\nabla u\right)\right) & =S_{0}f\\
\Leftrightarrow\left(I_{d}-T\right)u & =S_{0}f\\
\Leftrightarrow u & =\left(I_{d}-T\right)^{-1}S_{0}f.
\end{align*}

Now, to remove the restriction on the norm of $T,$we localize. Consider
the same problem posed on a small $B\left(0,\epsilon\right)$, and
rescale to $B_{1}.$